# Let $f$ be a measurable function from a measurable space $(X,S)$ and for every real numbers r and s, s>0 we define $frs$. Prove that frs ismeasurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a measurable function from a measurable space $(X,S)$ and for every real number $r$ and $s$, $s>0$  we define "shortened" functions $fr,s$ by
> $$fr,s(x) = \begin{cases}
> r &\text{if } f(x)>r,\\
> f(x) &\text{if } r \le f(x) \le s,\\
> -s &\text{if }  -s>f(x).
> \end{cases}$$
> Prove that $fr,s$ are measurable.

In the second case it is clear why $fr,s$ is measurable, for the first and third case is the implication coming from the fact that every constant function is measurable?

If $r≤f(x)≤s$, then $fr,s=f$ and since $f$ is measurable it means that $fr,s$ is measurable.

If $f(x)>r$, then we consider the set $\{x∈X|fr,s(x)>c\}=\{x∈X|r>c\}$. And we consider two cases: $r≤c$ and $r>c$.

If $r≤c$, then $\{x∈X|r>c\}$ is empty and it's in the sigma algebra (we know that the empty set is measurable).

If $r>c$, then $\{x∈X|r>c\}=X=(∅)c$ which means that X belongs to the sigma algebra as well. Similarly if $−s>f(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: There is no "second case [where] $g$ is measurable", nor "first and third case". Either $g$ (defined on $X$) is measurable, or it is not. Show your attempts to prove it is.

Comment: Again, you cannot reason by cases like this, as if $g$ were three functions at the same time (?) instead of one. You must prove $\forall c\in\Bbb R,$ $\{x\in X\mid g(x)>c\}\in S.$ This must not depend on the position of some $f(x)$ (coming out of nowhere) relatively to $r$ and $s.$ And writing that this set is equal to $\{x\in X\mid r>c\}$ makes no sense.

Comment: I think there are 2 misprints on the 3rd line of the definition of $g(x)$: two $-s$ instead of $s$. And that the hypothesis $s>0$ is irrelevant.

Comment: I did misprint it you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call $g$ (as initially) this "$fr,s$", and give it a more sensible definition, by covering and non-overlapping cases. For this, consider the partition of $X$ by three measurable subsets: $A:=f^{-1}((-\infty,r)),$
$B:=f^{-1}([r,s]),$ $C:=f^{-1}((s,+\infty)),$ and let
$$g(x):= \begin{cases}
r &\text{if }x\in A,\\
f(x) &\text{if }x\in B,\\
s &\text{if }x\in C.
\end{cases}$$
$\forall c\in\Bbb R$ $g^{-1}((c,+\infty))\cap A\in S$ since it is equal to $A$ or $\varnothing$ (depending whether $r$ is $>c$ or $\le c$). Similarily, $g^{-1}((c,+\infty))\cap C\in S.$ Finally, $g^{-1}((c,+\infty))\cap B=f^{-1}((c,+\infty))\cap B\in S.$ Thus, $g^{-1}((c,+\infty))\in S,$ as a union of three elements of $S.$ This ends the proof of measurability of $g.$

Comment: Thanks, this clarified things for me!